# PHP Subtracting two numbers should return zero, but it doesn't

Tags: php, math, floating-point-conversion

I have a function written in PHP that calculates account balances by subtracting all payments from all charges.

Unfortunately I have one account that is returning a value of  -4.5474735088646E-13 when I subtract 2716 from 2716.  I was kind of expecting a 0.

I calculate the value in my function like so

```
$accountbalance = (float)$totalcharges - (float)$totalpayments;
return $accountbalance;
```

The secondary issue is that when I format the account balance with two decimal places I end up with -0.00

```
number_format($accountbalance,2)
```

weird, or what?  What is causing this and how do I prevent it?

Comment: That's how floating point numbers work.

Comment: your -4.54... number is just a really really tiny number, almost zero.  Floating point imprecision for you.

Comment: Use `abs` to always have result as positive number

Comment: I actually need to see negative numbers in this case so abs won't work for me, but I believe one of you had recommended rounding (before editing your comment) and that seems to do the trick.  Also, sorry for posting a duplicate question.  Didn't realize.